# How to access a textfile entering its name in console? JAVA

Tags: java

What should one change in the code so that instead of entering a string in console, one enters a text name (exmple.txt) to get to the text (where the frequences will be counted)?

```
import java.io.*;
class FrequencyCount
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println ("Enter the Text: ");
        String s = br.readLine();
        System.out.println ("Enter suffix: ");
        String sub = br.readLine();
        int ind,count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i + sub.length() <= s.length(); i++)    
        {
            ind = s.indexOf(sub, i);
            if (ind >= 0)
            {
                count++;
                i = ind;
                ind = -1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Occurence of '"+sub+"' in String is "+count);

    }
}
```

Comment: go through the [file i/o tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)

Answer (score 0):

First of I will refactor your code like this in order to reuse the calculateOcurrences method. Then I would read the text file line by line and sum all the occurrences by line.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println ("Enter the file path: ");
        final String filePath = br.readLine();

        System.out.println ("Enter suffix: ");
        final String suffix = br.readLine();

        int count = 0;

        Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(filePath);

        Charset charset = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");
        try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path, charset)) {
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                 count = count + calculateOcurrences(line,suffix);
            }
        } catch (IOException x) {
            System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", x);
        }



        System.out.println("Occurence of '"+suffix+"' in String is "+count);

    }

    public static int calculateOcurrences(final String text, final String suffix) {
        int ocurrences = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i + suffix.length() <= text.length(); i++)
        {
            int indexOfOcurrence = text.indexOf(suffix, i);
            if (indexOfOcurrence >= 0)
            {
                ocurrences++;
                i = indexOfOcurrence;
            }
        }

        return ocurrences;
    }
}
```

Comment: as I understand this code reads the text, which will be entered in the console, but the problem is that I want to enter the filename with the extention only, not the text itself.

Comment: Check it now. I think that is what you were looking for.

Comment: I refactored the code in order to extract the method to make easier read the file and count the occurrences by line.